# Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'test::sum'

Tags: ruby, plugins, puppet, cicd

I'm trying to add a new function to an old puppet module and added a function with the following command.

```rb
pdk new function --type=v4 sum
```

this adds a file `lib/puppet/functions/test/sum.rb`

```js
# frozen_string_literal: true

# https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-specifications/blob/master/language/func-api.md#the-4x-api
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:"test::sum") do
  dispatch :sum do
    param 'Numeric', :a
    return_type 'Numeric'
  end
  # the function below is called by puppet and and must match
  # the name of the puppet function above. You can set your
  # required parameters below and puppet will enforce these
  # so change x to suit your needs although only one parameter is required
  # as defined in the dispatch method.
  def sum(x)
    x * 2
  end

  # you can define other helper methods in this code block as well
end
```

I can also see the function in `pdk console` when I run the `functions` command.

but when I try to call the function as follows

```
test::sum(5) # Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'test::sum'
test::sum.call(5) # Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'test::sum'
Deferred(test::sum, [5]).call # Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'test::sum'
```

Why it is not working? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I'm quite new to the puppet.

Comment: `:"test::sum"` is hard on the eyes, and I'm uncertain whether it does what you want.  I would use `"test::sum".to_sym`, myself.

Comment: With that said, I am uncertain whether Puppet supports namespace prefixes for functions.

Comment: The hard way is what's recommended on official docs. I'm certain that puppet supports namespacing because there is a deferred function in the module that is working fine.

Comment: Which version of Puppet are you using that with? And can you present a more complete example of how you are trying to call the function?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it seems both the syntax and the namespacing are how functions are described in the [Docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/functions_ruby_overview.html). *Note: I know absolutely nothing about Puppet so this is all I can realy contribute*

Comment: Thanks all, the issue was related to `spec_prep`. My latest code was not being fetched by console, so after spending a lot of time I was able to solve the issue by running this command. The above code is correct and functional.

```pdk bundle exec rake spec_prep```